# Image harddisk with clonezilla +install ubuntu+ copy data in that 1 TB external hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, disk-image, data-transfer, clonezilla

I have just bought 1TB external hard drive so i can image my laptop's hard disk with clonezilla and i can always revert back if i am in some unknown trouble. I have almost 100Gb on my C drive. If clone a image of that i my external hard drive. Can i store other data(games, movies, videos etc) into my external hard drive later. I'll be left with 900GB empty store would i be able to store data normally into the hard drive. Will storing data effect my clonezilla image?

Is it possible if i store data to that ex. hard drive then flashing image back to pc may encounter some problem. Or it would normally do the flashing irrespective of the data kept in the hard drive?

Also after cloning image i want to install ubuntu 14.04 in that external hard drive is it possible ?  and then store data in that hard drive ?

Please refer me to some video tutorials that i can follow. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you? Sure you can store other files besides a clonezilla image of a hdd on it. You can also make the external hdd bootable if you want but that would require you partition it.  What tutorials have you read that your confused by specifically?

Comment: @Ramhound means i have to partition my ex.HD for clone zilla and ubuntu? How to do that can you put a video tutorial link for it. So i can follow it :)

Comment: You don't know how to partition a disk?  There are tons of tutorials on how to do that.  **I don't have to link one to you.**

Comment: Clonezilla and Ubuntu has no problems writting to NTFS partitions.  Its not clear what your confused about, its also clear, that would be an entirely seperate question.

Comment: @Ramhound if i create 3 NTFS partitions of my Ex.Hard Drive and then store windows 8.1 img made by clonezilla to one and install ubuntu 14.04 to the 2nd NTFS partition is that fine?

Comment: Have you tried to do it?  I don't understand your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloneZilla comes in two flavours - server and "live".

If you plan to capture/restore many workstations or many different images then create yourself a CloneZilla server using Ubuntu, DRBL + CloneZilla.

If you plan to only capture one image as a "quick backup" of your home computer then you can download a "LiveCD" that can be burnt to CD or written to a bootable USB.

You will also need: A "destination" disk with greater capacity than your "source" disk. Most computers I know don't come with a 2TB disk (most not even a 1TB) so a 2TB USB hard disk should be perfect. It will ideally need to be partitioned and formatted with at least "ext" or "NTFS" (dare I say?). I have only ever used CloneZilla with an ext3 or ext4 filesystem. There are many tutorials on how to partition a disk for NTFS and ext3/ext4.

> For the sake of the OPs scenario: You could partition your 2TB disk to
>   have, say, 1TB of ext3/ext4 for your CloneZilla image file + your
>   Ubuntu/Linux data and then the other 1TB could be NTFS for your
>   Windows 8.

There are TWO ways of using CloneZilla - for precisely this sort of question.

**1) As a disk-to-disk clone - i.e. your disks become "mirrored"**

A disk-to-disk clone will copy one disk to the other by using DD. This will create a bit-by-bit duplicate of your disk. Used primarily for moving data from an old disk to a new or larger disk.

**2) As a disk-to-file clone so you can store multiple images on, say, a USB hard disk + be able to use the additional storage for other data.**

A disk-to-file uses other tools such as PartClone* which can have its output piped through, say, gzip to create a ".gz" zip file of your disk. CloneZilla can identify whether you have one or more partitions. It is a very powerful solution - I use it almost daily for duplicating Windows 7 and 8 and it hasn't caused any problems for over 4yrs.

*PartClone is a partition cloner, it can read many partition types but is exactly that. Be careful that it doesn't miss any boot sectors or other important disk data.

There are many tutorials available depending on how you want to image/restore using CloneZilla - too many to list. A starting tutorial can be found on the GoingLinux.com website (http://goinglinux.com/articles/ClonezillaLive.html)

Comment: how can i partition my ex.HD so i use 100 Gb for CloneZilla img, 300 Gb for ubuntu and rest 700 Gb for storing my daily downloaded stuff on windows 8.1 just by inserting external HD and copy that stuff to external HD....Please edit your answer. You just gave me background knowledge. I want HOW-TO-DO it. Thanks in advance.